# Running a docker container containing a .NET microservice without debugging

Tags: c#, .net, docker, containers, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm just getting into microservices with .NET and Docker containerization and I followed a simple tutorial that uses the default WeatherForecast example in c# to explain how to make a microservice and run it in a container.
I have difficulty understanding how to actually access the container that was built off of my microservice image without debugging in visual studio. I set the service port to 5000 and started debugging from visual studio, which builds the container (if non existent) and then runs it.
[image: Example]

The problem with this is, I can access the container (when debugging) by using `"localhost:5000/weatherforecast"` - which returns the raw JSON as expected.

But if I run the container without debugging (in the Docker Desktop app) and try to access it through my internal computer IP, so like `"192.168.1.13:5000/weatherforecast"` it can't reach the site, even though the container is being run in the same way as before, but not in the debugging way using Visual Studio.

If I run the microservice without debugging, it will create the container and run it, and it will work normally for both `"localhost:5000/weatherforecast"` and `"192.168.1.13:5000/weatherforecast"`, but as soon as I exit Visual Studio, the container gets removed as well.

I'm most likely missing something here. I also don't understand if the microservice should be running on the host PC (so my PC), for it to work in a container, but that wouldn't make sense.

Help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I assume you're using the URL as 192.168.1.13:5000/weatherforecast (note the colon instead of / in your question.) Docker seems like red herring in this case. If you run the code directly without debugging (thru dotnet run) can you access your site at URL mentioned above? Likely a firewall is blocking the access.

Comment: @RJ Yes, sorry, typo.

Comment: @RJ If I run ```dotnet run``` in the project directory I can only access it with ```localhost:5000/weatherforecast``` and not with ```192.168.1.13:5000/weatherforecast```, for the aforementioned it says connection refused. And it's not even running inside of a container, which I need it to do.

Comment: Yes, so, firewall. Assuming 192.168.1.13 is the IP of your dev box, you need to allow incoming connections on port 5000 through its firewall.